# How to make more than 2 conditions in where clause?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in MySQL Database matches,tournaments and countries. I want to have columns from those three tables which in the range of dates (between tow days) the query is :

```
SELECT matches.tournament_id 't_id',
       matches.localteam_ft_score,
       matches.visitorteam_ft_score,
       matches.match_time,
       matches.match_status,
       matches.match_date,
       matches.localteam_id,
       matches.visitorteam_id,
       matches.match_id,
       matches.id,
       matches.static_id,
       matches.localteam_name,
       matches.visitorteam_name,
       matches.halftime_score,
       tournaments.tournament_id,
       tournaments.league_link,
       tournaments.full_league_tr,
       countries.country_name
FROM matches
INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.id = matches.tournament_id
INNER JOIN countries ON tournaments.country_id = countries.country_id
WHERE match_status IN('AET','FT','Pen.','Awarded')
  AND countries.country_name='Worldcup'
  AND matches.match_date BETWEEN '19.05.2013' AND '19.06.2013'
```

The problem is : I can not get the records between these two dates it is just give me the matches with '19.05.2013' date I tried many ways to solve it but nothing works .
I want to know is it right to do three conditions in these way? is it the right way to get records between 2 dates?

Comment: What datatype is your `matches.match_date` field?

Comment: the datatype is varchar

Comment: Change the field to DATE and use YYYY-MM-DD for the format.

Comment: Well, there you have it, how should MySQL know that it has to interpret arbitrary strings as dates?

Comment: please refer this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I can not change the format this is a 'must' format

Comment: Then you need to reformat the fields to dates before you check they are within that range

Comment: try 'between str_to_date( '19.05.2013', '%d.%m.%Y' ) and ... '

Comment: @BaselShbeb Then you should change the guy who set up this specification. It is just a nonsense in a database. The workaround with `str_to_date()` makes it impossible to use an index on this column.

Comment: @BaselShbeb: MySQL has `DATE` field types for a reason.  If you "must" store dates as `VARCHAR`, then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: See my solution below. As the guys above advise you should really look at using the correct Date data type as that's what it's there for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your comment above, you need to change your data type of the match_date field to DATE (YYYY-MM-DD). MySQL cannot perform the between operation on a string. To do this you need to use the STR_TO_DATE function on the table column you wish to convert from a string to date format.

```
  SELECT matches.tournament_id 't_id', matches.localteam_ft_score,
   matches.visitorteam_ft_score, matches.match_time, matches.match_status,
   matches.match_date, matches.localteam_id, matches.visitorteam_id,
   matches.match_id, matches.id, matches.static_id,matches.localteam_name,
   matches.visitorteam_name, matches.halftime_score,  tournaments.tournament_id,
   tournaments.league_link, tournaments.full_league_tr, countries.country_name 
  FROM matches 
  INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.id = matches.tournament_id 
  INNER JOIN countries ON tournaments.country_id = countries.country_id 
  WHERE match_status IN('AET','FT','Pen.','Awarded') 
  AND countries.country_name='Worldcup' AND STR_TO_DATE(matches.match_date,'%d.%m.%Y') between '2013.05.19' and '2013.06.19'
```

Comment: Then use (str_to_date) function on the table column within your query above. That way the value in the column will be converted to a date format that can be compared against your criteria.

Comment: Don't you mean: `STR_TO_DATE(matches.match_date,'%d.%m.%Y') between '2013-05-19' and '2013-06-19'`?

Comment: Good spot. Sorry I don't work with SQL much anymore now I'm a front end developer so a bit rusty on the old ordering.

Comment: How are your dates written into the database? Exact format please.

Comment: like '19.05.2013' with the varchar datatype

Comment: There is your problem then. Use . instead or - in the between clause.

Comment: Thank you very much .Now it works because of the format of the value after "between" . But how that comes it is comparing values in different format ?

Comment: Because the str_to_date uses the Unix timestamp format meaning it appears in the format: YYYY-MM-DD. It's confusing at first but you get used to it. Ultimately you need to ensure that whoever setup your database is corrected on this issue as nobody at any level should be making this sort of data type error.

Answer (score 0):

check this one..

```
query1="date_format(str_to_date(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') between date_format(str_to_date('"+fromdate+"', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') and date_format(str_to_date('"+todate+"', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')";
```

Comment: Agree with the basic idea, but don't think the date_format is necessary. The str_to_date functions will do it.

Comment: Why do you have `DATE_FORMAT` here?  Why are you using the format `'%d/%m/%Y'`?

Comment: i just specify how to convert to specific format..if you have any other dobut please visit dev.mysql.com

Comment: What your code is doing is converting from a string in the format dd/mm/yyyy to a date, but then from that a date back to a string in the format mm/dd/yyyy. This new string format is no more useful than the original one to compare a date with. This stage is also unnecessary as once you have converted from the original string format into a date you can use the fields for comparison

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT matches.tournament_id 't_id', matches.localteam_ft_score,
    matches.visitorteam_ft_score, matches.match_time, matches.match_status,
    matches.match_date, matches.localteam_id, matches.visitorteam_id,
    matches.match_id, matches.id, matches.static_id,matches.localteam_name,
    matches.visitorteam_name, matches.halftime_score,  tournaments.tournament_id,
    tournaments.league_link, tournaments.full_league_tr, countries.country_name 
    FROM matches 
    INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.id = matches.tournament_id 
    INNER JOIN countries ON tournaments.country_id = countries.country_id 
    WHERE match_status IN('AET','FT','Pen.','Awarded') 
    AND countries.country_name='Worldcup' 
AND (matches.match_date between '19.05.2013' and '19.06.2013' or matches.match_date     between 'd1'and 'd2')
```